# android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE triggers so many complete states

Tags: android, wifimanager

In my broadcast reciever, I am using the below code to identify if the Wifi is connected or disconnected. It works perfectly, but the  wifiInfo.getSupplicantState().equals(SupplicantState.COMPLETED) returns true for atleast 4 to 7 times while connecting wifi.

Can I use  SupplicantState.ASSOCIATING as it seems to be triggering only once ?

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if( wifiInfo.getSupplicantState().equals(SupplicantState.COMPLETED)){ //Connected ??
        //Do Something
    }
    else if( wifiInfo.getSupplicantState().equals(SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED)){       
        //Do Something
    }
}
else{
    //Wifi Adaptor disabled;
}
```

Here is the intent-filter I am using for BroadCast Receiver

```
<receiver
    android:name="WifiReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,you cant use because from the docs of `ASSOCIATING`

> Trying to associate with a BSS/SSID. This state is entered when
>   wpa_supplicant has found a suitable BSS to associate with and the
>   driver is configured to try to associate with this BSS in ap_scan=1
>   mode. When using ap_scan=2 mode, this state is entered when the driver
>   is configured to try to associate with a network using the configured
>   SSID and security policy.

means it is in progress.
Also if you think about `ASSOCIATED`

> Association completed. This state is entered when the driver reports
>   that association has been successfully completed with an AP. If IEEE
>   802.1X is used (with or without WPA WPA2), wpa_supplicant remains in this state until the IEEE 802.1X/EAPOL authentication has been
>   completed.

Hence these all are in a state when it is not connected to the wifi AP completely.

So,the best is only using `COMPLETED`

For handling that repeated callback use a boolean which gets true in if block and false in else block.And will go inside if block when it is false only.

Comment: Tnx. I can use a variable. 
But, How can I know its just repeated event. 
This could be user trying to connect any other wifi too right?
Is there a group id to identify same set of requests ?

Comment: when connecting to another wifi network then it will first disconnect then connect. hence your disconnect I mean the else block will fire once.

Comment: SSID is always there!